# What is the purpose/example for force:navigateToReactNativeApp event?

Tags: event, force, react-native

I'm wondering the idea behind this as I don't understand which kind of situation you will use this.

More info [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToReactNativeApp/specification).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React is a programming technology created by Facebook that provides a cross-platform interface for creating applications. A specific extension of React, called forcereact, is an implementation that provides Salesforce-specific features, and is part of the Mobile SDK. You'll want to start from this [trail](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/mobile_sdk_react_native), which gives you a quick crash course in forcereact, as well as links to an example application, documentation, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know about React and React native and also I have been investigating on it using the Salesforce Mobile SDK for Android/iOS but what I would like to know is, if I understand well, this will be a separated/isolated app  - apk/ipa files -  from what is built with Salesforce Lightning Components so is a kind of method to connect both? Probably some real situation which you will use this method on your lightning components ? Thanks

Comment: @danigonlinea I don't have a real reason to use it, because I don't do any mobile development at this time. But yes, it's a way that you can load your native app directly from Salesforce on a supported device that has the app installed, and even provide parameters to your app if necessary. For example, you might have a mobile app that links to another system (inventory management, tracking, whatever), and you can then provide a component inside Salesforce to load that app with a parameter. This event is something you won't use if you're not using react.